# Can I use bash brace expansion in for loop?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, shell

I have some files in directory: `touch dir1/dir2/bad\ name{1..4}`. I would like to move those files (`bad name1 - bad name4`) from `dir2` to `dir1`, as well as rename them at once. Because these files have bad name, I will simply take them as `ls bad*`. Now to move them as I want, I would try `for i in $(ls *bad); do mv $i ../anothername{a..d}; done` . The problem I ma trying to solve is how to make one to one mapping (between loop and expansion) - that is

*for one iteration of for loop make one expansion of braces*

I put `bad\ name` deliberately, because I could do `mv bad\ name{1..4} ../anothername{a..d}`, and thus no need for `for loop` and thus not the problem, But I want to take these files with `file expansion` `*` - `ls bad*` and map them in for loop concurrently with `brace expansion` ([gnu brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)). Is it possible, or braces cannot expand in for loop in one iteration? And thus the only option is do it with braces on both sides of mv (as in `mv bad\ name{1..4} ../anothername{a..d}`)

Comment: `mv bad\ name{1..4} ../anothername{a..d}` will not do what you want. There is just one target in `mv …`. About `for i in $(ls *bad)`: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: If there is just one target, how can I rename multiple files (and thus multiple target) at once with `mv` command?

Comment: You cannot rename multiple files with one `mv`. To do this with `mv` you need to call `mv` multiple times.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I can do it in for loop, or is there another command for this purpose?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, I cannot. Because the link you provided is only dealing with truncating prefixies of files, but I want to actually change, rename all files to something different. That is the reason I have asked how to use for loop and braces at once. If I do `for file in bad\ name{1..4}; do ...` I have files as the iterator, I would need `for name in {a..d}; do for file in *; do mv $file ../$name; done; done` which is what DO NOT want (double loop) becuase it does not even work, therefor I am asking about braces expansion

Comment: OK, I understand. My bad.

Comment: Well, if the first and second brace expansions pair and are each of constant length (not necessarily the same) and if the first is a number, one could indeed get away without Bash arrays, simply by abusing the numbers as index into a string substitution (with the substituted character, a number, being an index into a string with the replacements) ... but `$(ls)` [is a _really really_ bad idea in a `for`-loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @0xC0000022L I do not get it. Can you please provide an example of  `simply by abusing the numbers as index into a string`, how can one index with strings?

Comment: String substitution plain and simple ... [`${string:position:length}`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose given the tool (Bash) no solution will be really straightforward, in the sense of being particularly readable. As outlined in a comment to your question you could also devise a way that works purely with strings (no arrays). However, arrays have the advantage of allowing for replacements of varying lengths.

Anyway, here's my example (and that `echo` is intentional, so this doesn't immediately go about its business should someone paste and execute the script):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
replacements="aabbccdd"
let step=2
let max=$((${#replacements}/step))
for ((i=1;i<=$max;i++)); do
    echo mv bad\ name$i ../anothername${replacements:$((i*step-step)):$step}
done
```

### Explanation:

(Tested and found to be working with Bash 4.4.20)

- `step` is set to the length of one individual replacement
- `replacements` holds a string from which we will cut pieces of length `step`
- the C-style for loop simply uses `i` as numeric index variable
- `${replacements:...:...}` performs the individual replacement

  - `$((i*step-step))` is an arithmetic expression and the expression is exactly what it seems to be: `i*step-step` ... the `-step` is there to get to a zero-based index into the string ...
  - `$step` is the length of each piece we cut out of the `replacements` string

### Limitations:

- this code assumes we want to start at 1 and go continuously up to the given maximum, that can of course be adjusted
- this code no longer uses a brace expansion, although it could arguably be done by way of an `eval` ... but it would not aid readability ...
- this code requires uniform length for the replacements (the other proposed solution with an array does not have this limitation!)

Answer (score 1):

Prepare two arrays:

```
src=( bad\ name{1..4} )
dst=( anothername{a..d} )
```

Confirm there are 4 elements in each:

```
echo "${#src[@]}"
echo "${#dst[@]}"
```

Then in `dir2`:

```
for i in {0..3}; do mv "${src[i]}" "../${dst[i]}"; done
```

Indexed arrays are indexed from `0`, that's why `{0..3}`, not `{1..4}` in the loop.