# Matching variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Trying to ping IP and return result with the HOSTNAME.
first ip is responsive second is not, but the script prints all HOSTNAMES
How do I match IP (i) with the HOSTNAME (h)?
Tried:

```
for i in 10.10.63.84 10.10.100.49; do for h in TEST NOCON
do
#Pinging IPs and report if success
        ping -c 1 $i &> /dev/null;
           if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "$h is alive"
                else
                        echo "Please reboot $h!"
           fi
done
done

result:
TEST is alive
NOCON is alive
Please reboot TEST!
Please reboot NOCON!

Should be
TEST is alive
Please reboot NOCON!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested for loops means you're working with the cross-product:
10.10.63.84 TEST
10.10.63.84 NOCON
10.10.100.49 TEST
10.10.100.49 NOCON

You actually want a 1:1 mapping. Use an associative array for that:

```bsh
declare -A hosts=(
    [10.10.63.84]="TEST"
    [10.10.100.49]="NOCON"
)

# iterate over the array _keys_
for ip in "${!hosts[@]}"; do
    if ping -c 1 "$ip" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "${hosts[$ip]} is alive"
    else
        echo "Please reboot ${hosts[$ip]}!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note: with an associative array the order one gets from `"${!hosts[@]}"` has nothing to do with the order one chooses while declaring. If the order is important, use an indexed array(s). Two possibilities in this case: two indexed arrays, one for IP addresses, the other for names (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1542620/432690)); or an associative array like above plus an indexed array of keys that defines the order (compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161460/10765659))